# NodeJs docker container failed to connect with MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, express, docker-compose

I was trying to dockerize my nodejs-mysql application. I have two containers Nodejs and Mysql. Mysql container has an open port to 3306.

Here is my Dockerfile: 
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g nodemon

RUN npm install

COPY . .

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  express-server:
    build:
      context: .
    environment: 
        MYSQL_HOST: mysql-service
        MYSQL_USER: 'root'
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'warehouse'
    entrypoint: ["npm", "start"]
    ports:
      - "8080:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - mysql-service
  mysql-service:
    image: mysql
    environment: 
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'warehouse'
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - mysql-db-config-data:/etc/mysql
volumes:
  mysql-db-data:
  mysql-db-config-data:
```

The Error which is popping up:

```
Building express-server
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.009MB
Step 1/6 : FROM node:latest
 ---> 7105279fa2ab
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ca2eb57497d7
Step 3/6 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b9a292d28bde
Step 4/6 : RUN npm install -g nodemon
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3d6a9cac2364
Step 5/6 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4a91bb3f0306
Step 6/6 : COPY . .
 ---> 296ff4a8ff49
Successfully built 296ff4a8ff49
Successfully tagged nodejs-mysql-docker-compose_express-server:latest
Recreating nodejs-mysql-docker-compose_mysql-service_1 ... done
Recreating nodejs-mysql-docker-compose_express-server_1 ... done
Attaching to nodejs-mysql-docker-compose_mysql-service_1, nodejs-mysql-docker-compose_express-server_1
mysql-service_1   | 2021-06-26 10:15:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.25-1debian10 started.
mysql-service_1   | 2021-06-26 10:15:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql-service_1   | 2021-06-26 10:15:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.25-1debian10 started.
mysql-service_1   | 2021-06-26T10:15:53.360045Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25) starting as process 1
mysql-service_1   | 2021-06-26T10:15:53.423308Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql-service_1   | 2021-06-26T10:15:54.886687Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
express-server_1  | 
express-server_1  | > nodejs-mysql-docker-compose@1.0.0 start
express-server_1  | > nodemon app.js
express-server_1  | 
express-server_1  | [nodemon] 2.0.7
express-server_1  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
express-server_1  | [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
express-server_1  | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
express-server_1  | [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
mysql-service_1   | 2021-06-26T10:15:55.196958Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
express-server_1  | Server is running at: 8000
mysql-service_1   | 2021-06-26T10:15:55.760561Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql-service_1   | 2021-06-26T10:15:55.762472Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
express-server_1  | /app/mysql-connect.js:14
express-server_1  |         throw err
express-server_1  |         ^
express-server_1  | 
express-server_1  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:3306
express-server_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1133:16)
express-server_1  |     --------------------
express-server_1  |     at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
express-server_1  |     at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
express-server_1  |     at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
express-server_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/mysql-connect.js:12:12)
express-server_1  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
express-server_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
express-server_1  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
express-server_1  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
express-server_1  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
express-server_1  |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18) {
express-server_1  |   errno: -111,
express-server_1  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
express-server_1  |   syscall: 'connect',
express-server_1  |   address: '172.19.0.2',
express-server_1  |   port: 3306,
express-server_1  |   fatal: true
express-server_1  | }
express-server_1  | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
mysql-service_1   | 2021-06-26T10:15:55.808173Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql-service_1   | 2021-06-26T10:15:55.992990Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.25'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

How to resolve this error? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: is the used ip for mysql the ip of your the pc or the nodejs docker container? docker has its own ip on your system

Comment: Its `mysql-service` container ip address right?

Comment: you can either provide the ip of the mysql docker container or the ip of your system. you mapped the port so its fine to provide the system ip to you mysql packge in the node app

Comment: It looks like a timing issue,  you may have to change your app code to retry after a delay.